# Store computer/admin password in the password manager

Tags: macos, security, passwords, administrator, malware

I have two accounts on my Mac: a standard user account for everyday activities and an administrator account. I always use the standard user account.

I have a password manager (1Password) installed on my Mac in the standard user account. I wonder, Is it safe to put my standard user password and especially my administrator password into the password manager?

Since there is a window when the data inside the password manager is unencrypted (when it's unlocked) a potential malware that was installed in the standard user scope without admin rights and didn't possess my Mac credentails now can steal them from the password manager and with my current user password and especially the administrator password it can do much bigger harm to my system than without them.
Is my reasoning correct here?

Comment: I don't think that your password manager's vault is readable for everyone when it's unlocked. The operating system should isolate processes from each other and not let everyone look at others' private parts.

Comment: @gronostaj but how does it isolate the file system? If my password manager stores the data under my user folder, any other process that runs in that user scope can access all files in the current user directory, no?

Comment: It doesn't save the unencrypted vault anywhere (or at least no sane manager would). It's only stored in memory.

Comment: @gronostaj sounds reasonable. Doesn't a process without admin rights can read other process memory?

Comment: I couldn't quickly find any information to confirm this. It would be sane to assume so, but I know that some older OSes didn't have such protection in place.

Comment: If you have malware on your system which can read data from processes of other users your security is already broken. That malware already can do whatever harm it wants, without requiring passwords.

Comment: @nohillside thanks for your reply, but it looks like what you are describing isn't my case. 
I am using my computer from the standard user, the password manager runs on behalf of the standard user as well and it stores its data under the standard user home directory.
My question is, is it possible for a malware that also runs only in the standard user scope (without admin rights, since it doesn't know my admin credentials) to read data from the password manager memory?
Thanks!

Comment: Can a process read the memory of others? Sure, that‘s how debuggers work. Can a process read login details from a password manager? Maybe, depending on how the password manager manages its memory. Can a process find your admin password with that? Depends, how would the process determine that a specific entry/memory location is your admin password?

Comment: @nohillside thanks for your detailed answer. Since there is a lot of "maybe" and "depends" I think it's better to not put it there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any program cannot just read the contents of your 1Password windows with the passwords. Random programs also cannot read the memory of other processes. If a program wants to do that, it needs further permissions (such as you would give to for example a debugger - though even ordinary debuggers cannot attach to just any process on the system).

In essence, given that there are no weaknesses in the implementations, you could consider it “safe” to store those passwords in your password manager.

However, weaknesses do exist and they are sometimes exploited by malware!

Do you have a specific reason for storing your own user password in 1Password? I cannot see why you would want to do that under normal circumstances, so I would just avoid doing that in any case. If you really need to, it sounds like you might be using the same password for multiple things, which is not a good idea.

On the other hand, I really doubt malware exists that try to grab your admin password from 1Password. Such malware would rather grab all passwords for your cloud accounts and send them to the controller. I.e. they would rather have access to your Google account, AppleID, Amazon account, etc. whatever you have in there - rather than the Administrator account on your local PC... mostly because if the malware can read your 1Password passwords, it already has Administrator-like privileges on your system.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you. The only reason to store the admin password in 1Password was to have a place to look it up in case I forget it. But I agree, 1Password doesn't feel to be very suitable for that and I will find another place.